# Do I need to confirm my medical appointment?

Tags: usa, health

I am traveling in the US. I scheduled an appointment with some physician (no worries, I got a medical insurance). I know that sometimes patients in the US get called to confirm their appointment, but the area I am currently hiking has no phone coverage, so it's likely I cannot answer such calls. Can failure to answer such calls lead to appointment cancellation?

Comment: are you currently out of range ?

Comment: @Max yes that's correct.

Comment: can't you contact someone (via the interwebs, since it's working ) that can confirm your appointment for you ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel... really.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis make sure you keep your comment  in the clipboard because you're going to need it quite often then

Comment: @Max I could but would only if necessary.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled why since you have wifi or data, you can't use wifi calling, Skype, online chat or email or one of the many other non-telephone means to contact the doctor's office if this is a major concern? Contact them somehow at your leisure to confirm the appointment. Not all doctors offices have the same policies so it is impossible for anyone to answer this.

Comment: @HarryVervet many physicians just use phone + fax. I know, that's stupid, but that's the way it is. Any idea for  [Leaving a voice message by typing a text](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23201/903)? I can fax from websites, but sometimes I don't even have the fax number.

Comment: Why not let someone else call on your behalf?

Comment: @CountIblis I would rather do it only if necessary.

Comment: I guess you should have bought [this phone](https://www.iridium.com/products/details/iridiumextreme).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a life-hack, not travel as defined by the community. Perhaps [outdoors.se] can give some useful advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call now (or as soon as you can) and confirm your appointment for date and time, and tell them you will be hiking and will be out of range until that date.

I don't see any problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

It might lead to cancellation of your appointment, but if you notify them in advance that you will be incommunicado then you will almost certainly be able to avoid that outcome.  In other words, the cancellation should not be automatic and unavoidable.

Source: I did this once for a dental appointment.